# Articles and Article Management in Salesforce1 Mobile App

Tags: salesforce1-app, mobile, knowledge

Can Article and Article Management tabs be exposed on the Salesforce1 mobile app?

Comment: good question, I did found an idea about this on the idea-exchange that would suggest that indeed, it's not fully functional on the Salesforce1 app. https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l0q5AAA